# How does eval() treat a string object differently from a primitive string value?

Tags: javascript

I was reading in my Javascript book and it was talking about the difference between these two statements.

```
var s = "hello world"; // A primitive string value
var S = new String("hello world"); // A String object
```

I understand the difference but the book also mentioned (as like a little side note) that **eval() will handle these differently** but didn't mention how.

I tried looking around a google and couldn't find anything so I want to example.com and started messing around with it. I couldn't see a difference in the way that they are handled.

My question is: **How does the eval() method treat these differently?**

Comment: Which book were you reading?  Might as well give a citation.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String):

`String` primitives and `String` objects also give different results
when using `eval`. Primitives passed to `eval` are treated as source code;
`String` objects are treated as all other objects are, by returning the
object. For example:

> ```
> s1 = "2 + 2";               // creates a string primitive
> s2 = new String("2 + 2");   // creates a String object
> console.log(eval(s1));      // returns the number 4
> console.log(eval(s2));      // returns the string "2 + 2"
> ```

Comment: That makes sense now. Thanks for the quick and simple response. I'll mark the answer accepted as soon as I am able.

Comment: Glad we were able to help!

Answer (score 13):

Consider this:

```
str = "alert('foo')";
obj = new String("alert('foo')");

eval(str); // produces an alert popup with 'foo' in it
eval(obj); // returns "alert('foo')" as a string


str = "arglebargle";
obj = new String('arglebargle');

eval(str); // reference error: arglebargle is not defined
eval(obj); // string: "arglebargle"
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I saw the other answer first and accepted it but this adds to my understanding of the concept.